# measuring performance of directshow filter

Tags: c++, performance, windows-ce, directshow

I have built a mp3 decoder directshow filter for win CE , and I want to measure the performance of the decoder. I found two macros from msdn site, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms932254.aspx which is declared in the *measure.h* header file in base classes.
It is explained in the *measure.h* file that these macros will expand to nothing unless macro PERF is defined. but once I enable the macro, I get link error

> "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Msr_Start() referneced in
>   function function "public: virtual long_cdecl
>   CMP3Decoder::Recieve(Struct IMediaSample
>   *)"(?Recieve@CMP3Decoder@@UAAJPAUIMediaSample@@@Z)

I tried to dump the symbols in strmbase.lib, but I couldn't find any symbol name Msr_Start in it. also I searched the whole base classes folder source code.

where can I find the definition for these functions?

Or is there any other ways to measure the performance of the filter?

CMP3Decoder::recieve() function is as follows

HRESULT CMP3Decoder::Receive(IMediaSample *pSample)
{

```
HRESULT hr;
ASSERT(pSample);
if(pSample == NULL || m_MP3DecHandle == NULL)
{
    return E_FAIL;
}

ASSERT (m_pOutput != NULL) ;

// Start timing the transform (if PERF is defined)
MSR_START(m_idTransform);

// have the derived class transform the data

hr = MP3StartDecode(pSample);//, pOutSample);

// Stop the clock and log it (if PERF is defined)
MSR_STOP(m_idTransform);

if (FAILED(hr)) {
    //DbgLog((LOG_TRACE,1,TEXT("Error from transform")));
} else {
    // the Transform() function can return S_FALSE to indicate that the
    // sample should not be delivered; we only deliver the sample if it's
    // really S_OK (same as NOERROR, of course.)
    if (hr == NOERROR) {
        //hr = m_pOutput->Deliver(pOutSample);
        m_bSampleSkipped = FALSE;   // last thing no longer dropped
    } else {
        // S_FALSE returned from Transform is a PRIVATE agreement
        // We should return NOERROR from Receive() in this cause because returning S_FALSE
        // from Receive() means that this is the end of the stream and no more data should
        // be sent.
        if (S_FALSE == hr) {

            //  Release the sample before calling notify to avoid
            //  deadlocks if the sample holds a lock on the system
            //  such as DirectDraw buffers do
            //pOutSample->Release();
            m_bSampleSkipped = TRUE;
            if (!m_bQualityChanged) {
                NotifyEvent(EC_QUALITY_CHANGE,0,0);
                m_bQualityChanged = TRUE;
            }
            return NOERROR;
        }
    }
}
// release the output buffer. If the connected pin still needs it,
// it will have addrefed it itself.
//pOutSample->Release();

return hr;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee492675.aspx), you need to link to Strmiids.lib.

> Or is there any other ways to measure the performance of the filter?

To measure performance of a filter, I typically insert a custom trans-in-place filter before and after the filter to be measured. The trans-in-place filter outputs sample times and current time in high resolution to a log file. You can calculate filter processing time by subtracting the before current times from the after and averaging those, etc. Also, the file-io should only be done after stopping the graph as you don't want to interfere with the measurement itself.

Update:
Dumping the symbols in Strmiids.lib seems to confirm that Msr_xxx functions are not defined in Strmiids.lib. Looks like the MSDN article is incorrect.

Comment: currently i have  linked against strmbase.lib,Strmiids.lib,Ole32.lib,Ole32auth.lib,Uuid.lib libraries, according to [msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/subscriptions/downloads/aa451221). strmiids.lib gives CLSIDs and IIDs of standard components I think

Comment: I found a workaround, according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using QueryPerformanceCounter(). but, if I could get the details about MSR_START and MSR_STOP, would be great